# Существует ли метод в java, который можно вызвать, чтобы проверить ,нажата ли кнопка?

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Писал змейку на java, разбирался с графикой, и возникла проблема. В методе paint я вызываю сначала paintComponent, а потом repaint, из-за этого программа не может считывать нажатия клавиш. Есть ли какой-то метод, который можно было бы вызвать между repaint и paintComponent, чтобы считывать ввод с клавиатуры? То есть, например, метод проверяет, нажата ли какая-либо клавиша, если да - возвращает код клавиши или записывает ее код в переменную, иначе - ничего не делает, либо возвращает знач-е по умолчанию, допустим -1. Или, может, есть другое решение проблемы. Как мне считывать нажатия клавиш в данном коде?

---

Чтобы было более понятно, какой метод мне нужен[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ниже приведу код `

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    private int[][] a = new int[10][10]; //массив, хранящий координаты всех объектов на игровом поле
    private int cellSide = 15; //сторона квадратов, из к-рых состоит тело змейки
    private int lives = 3; //кол-во жизней (длина) змейки
    private int jHead = 3; //коодинаты головы
    private int iHead = 1;
    private int jTail = 1; //коодинаты хвоста
    private int iTail = 1;
    private int iEat = 3;
    private int jEat = 3;
    private int i,j;
    private String dir = "r"; //текущее направление движения змейки (по умолчанию - направо)
    private String nextDir; //следующее
    private boolean isGameRun; //перемення содержит информацию, запущена ли игра
    private int delayMillis = 150; //задержка между очистками и перерисовками игрового окна
    //влияет на скорсть движения змеи

private BufferedImage buffer;

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    paintComponent(g);
    repaint();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(buffer == null || isGameRun) {
            rebuildBuffer();
        }
        g.drawImage(buffer,0,0,this);
}
private void rebuildBuffer() {
    buffer = new BufferedImage(a.length*cellSide, a.length*cellSide,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 1) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.fillRect(j * cellSide, i * cellSide, cellSide, cellSide);
            } else if (a[i][j] > 1) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.fillRect(j * cellSide, i * cellSide, cellSide, cellSide);
            } else if (a[i][j] == -1) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.fillRect(j * cellSide, i * cellSide, cellSide, cellSide);
            }
        }
    }
    if (lives >= 3 && isItBites() == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] == lives) a[i][j] = 0;
                if (a[i][j] == 1) {
                    iHead = i;
                    jHead = j;
                }
            }
        }//определяем координаты хвоста змейки и стираем его
        //определяем координаты головы змейки и записываем их
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                if (a[i][j] > 0) a[i][j]++;

        } //увеличиваем числа змейки на 1
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                if (a[i][j] == lives) {
                    iTail = i;
                    jTail = j;
                }
        } //записываем новый хвост

        moveGrow(dir, nextDir); //запускаем ф-цию, определяющую, где поставить голову змейки в след ходе

        if (((dir.equals("r") || dir.equals("l")) && (nextDir.equals("u") || nextDir.equals("d"))) ||
                ((dir.equals("u") || dir.equals("d")) && (nextDir.equals("l") || nextDir.equals("r"))))
            dir = nextDir; //предыдущему направлению движения присваивается текущее
    }

    else {g2d.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 18));
        g2d.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        g2d.drawString("GAME OVER", (a.length*cellSide)/2, (a.length*cellSide)/2-30);
        removeKeyListener(this);
        //основная информация о местоположении змейки в массиве на момент конца игры, нужно для дебага
        for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(" " + Arrays.toString(a[i])+ "\n");
        System.out.print("\n\n" + "dir = "+dir + " nextDir = " + nextDir+"\n");
        System.out.print("координаты хвоста " + "(" +iTail+"; "+jTail+ ") ");
        System.out.print("координаты головы " + "(" +iHead+"; "+jHead+ ")\n");
        isGameRun = false;

    }
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(delayMillis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }

}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int kCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(kCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) nextDir = "u";
    else if(kCode == KeyEvent.VK_S)nextDir = "d";
    else if(kCode == KeyEvent.VK_A)nextDir = "l";
    else if(kCode == KeyEvent.VK_D)nextDir = "r";
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setSize(500,500);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jFrame.add(new Game());

}
Game() {

    a[iTail][jTail] = 3;
    a[1][2] = 2;
    a[iHead][jHead] = 1;
    a[iEat][jEat]=-1;
    nextDir = dir;
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(150,150);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        private Dimension lastSize;
        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            if (!getSize().equals(lastSize)) {
                rebuildBuffer();
                lastSize = getSize();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            if (!getSize().equals(lastSize)) {
                rebuildBuffer();
                lastSize = getSize();
            }
        }
    });
    isGameRun = true;
}

private void setRandomEat()
{
    int is = 0;
    while(is == 0) {
        i = 1+(int)(Math.random()*(a.length-2));
        j = 1+(int)(Math.random()*(a.length-2));
        if (a[i][j] == 0 && i!=iEat && j!=jEat)
        {
            is = 1; iEat = i; jEat = j;
            a[iEat][jEat]=-1;
            if(delayMillis > 50) delayMillis-=10;
        }
    }
} //ф-ция присваивает координатам еды случайные значения в диапозоне

private int isItBites()
{
    for(i=0; i< a.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j < a.length;j++)
        {
            if (iHead > 0 && nextDir.equals("u") && a[iHead-1][jHead]>0) return -1;
            else if (iHead < a.length-1 && nextDir.equals("d") && a[iHead+1][jHead]>0) return -1;
            else if (jHead < a.length-1 && nextDir.equals("r") && a[iHead][jHead+1]>0) return -1;
            else if (jHead > 0 && nextDir.equals("l") && a[iHead][jHead-1]>0) return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
} //ф-ция определяет, было ли столкновение змейки с ее телом или со стеной


private void moveGrow(String dir, String nextDir) {
    //предыдущее направление движения - вправо
    if(dir.equals("r"))
    {
        if(nextDir.equals("u")) { //верно
            if (iHead > 0)--iHead;
            else iHead = a.length-1;
        }
        else if(nextDir.equals("d")) { //верно
            if (iHead < a.length - 1) ++iHead;
            else iHead = 0;
        }
        else if(dir.equals("r")) { //верно
            if (jHead < a.length - 1) ++jHead;
            else jHead = 0;
        }
        a[iHead][jHead] = 1;
        if(iHead==iEat && jHead==jEat) //верно
        {

            if(jTail > 0)--jTail;
            else jTail=a.length-1;
            a[iTail][jTail] = ++lives;
            setRandomEat();
        }
    } //предыдущее направление движения - влево
    else if(dir.equals("l"))
    {
        if(nextDir.equals("u")) { //верно
            if (iHead > 0) --iHead;
            else iHead = a.length - 1;
        }
        else if(nextDir.equals("d")) { //верно
            if (iHead < a.length -1) ++iHead;
            else iHead = 0;
        }
        else if(dir.equals("l")) { //верно
            if (jHead > 0) --jHead;
            else jHead = a.length - 1;
        }
        a[iHead][jHead] = 1;
        if(iHead==iEat && jHead==jEat) //верно
        {
            if(jTail < a.length -1)++jTail;
            else jTail=0;
            a[iTail][jTail] = ++lives;
            setRandomEat();
        }
    } //предыдущее направление движения - вверх
    else if(dir.equals("u"))
    {
        if(nextDir.equals("r")) { //верно
            if(jHead < a.length - 1) ++jHead;
            else jHead = 0;
        }
        else if(nextDir.equals("l")) { //верно
            if(jHead > 0) --jHead;
            else jHead = a.length - 1;
        }
        else if(dir.equals("u")) { //верно
            if(iHead > 0) --iHead;
            else iHead = a.length - 1;
        }
        a[iHead][jHead] = 1;
        if(iHead==iEat && jHead==jEat) //верно
        {
            if(iTail < a.length - 1) ++iTail;
            else iTail = 0;
            a[iTail][jTail] = ++lives;
            setRandomEat();
        }
    } //предыдущее направление движения - вниз
    else if(dir.equals("d"))
    {
        if(nextDir.equals("r")) { //верно
            if(jHead < a.length - 1) ++jHead;
            else jHead = 0;
        }
        else if(nextDir.equals("l")) { //верно
            if(jHead > 0) --jHead;
            else jHead = a.length - 1;
        }
        else if(dir.equals("d")) { //верно
            if(iHead < a.length - 1) ++iHead;
            else iHead = 0;
        }
        a[iHead][jHead] = 1;
        if(iHead==iEat && jHead==jEat) //верно
        {
            if(iTail > 0) --iTail;
            else iTail = a.length - 1;
            a[iTail][jTail] = ++lives;
            setRandomEat();
        }
    }
}

}

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто нельзя вызывать `repaint` из метода `paint`...

Comment: А что вызывать тогда из метода paint? Кстати, проблему решил. Добавил слушателя не к jpanel, а к jframe - и все заработало